# Replacing libpng-devel (1.5.3) with libpng12-devel RPMs on CentOS

Tags: centos, rpm

I have a CentOS 6.4 box with a lot of other RPMs.

I want to replace libpng-devel with libpng12.devel. If I do an `rpm -e libpng-devel` I get the following:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
    pkgconfig(libpng) is needed by (installed) cairo-devel-1.10.2-7.el6.x86_64
    pkgconfig(libpng15) is needed by (installed) gdk-pixbuf2-devel-2.26.1-1.el6.x86_64
    libpng-devel is needed by (installed) cairo-devel-1.10.2-7.el6.x86_64
    libpng-devel is needed by (installed) gtk2-devel-2.24.10-1.el6.x86_64
    libpng-devel(x86-64) = 2:1.5.13-2.el6 is needed by (installed) libpng-static-2:1.5.13-2.el6.x86_64
```

Deleting those takes me down a rabbit hole.

I tried yum downgrade and got the following:

```
[mono@localhost ~]$ sudo yum downgrade libpng
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Downgrade Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.net.cen.ct.gov
 * extras: mirror.dattobackup.com
 * rpmforge: repoforge.mirror.constant.com
 * updates: mirror.umd.edu
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libpng.x86_64 2:1.2.49-1.el6_2 will be a downgrade
---> Package libpng.x86_64 2:1.5.13-2.el6 will be erased
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: gdk-pixbuf2-devel-2.26.1-1.el6.x86_64 (installed)
           Requires: libpng15.so.15()(64bit)
           Removing: 2:libpng-1.5.13-2.el6.x86_64 (installed)
               libpng15.so.15()(64bit)
           Downgraded By: 2:libpng-1.2.49-1.el6_2.x86_64 (base)
               Not found
Error: Package: 2:libpng-devel-1.5.13-2.el6.x86_64 (installed)
           Requires: libpng(x86-64) = 2:1.5.13-2.el6
           Removing: 2:libpng-1.5.13-2.el6.x86_64 (installed)
               libpng(x86-64) = 2:1.5.13-2.el6
           Downgraded By: 2:libpng-1.2.49-1.el6_2.x86_64 (base)
               libpng(x86-64) = 2:1.2.49-1.el6_2
Error: Package: 2:libpng-devel-1.5.13-2.el6.x86_64 (installed)
           Requires: libpng15.so.15()(64bit)
           Removing: 2:libpng-1.5.13-2.el6.x86_64 (installed)
               libpng15.so.15()(64bit)
           Downgraded By: 2:libpng-1.2.49-1.el6_2.x86_64 (base)
               Not found
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
[mono@localhost ~]$
```

Downgrading the others took me down a similar rabbithole.

I tried localinstall/localupdate and they did not seem to work either:

```
[mono@localhost ~]$ sudo yum --nogpgcheck localinstall ~/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/libpng12-devel-1.2.50-3.el6.x86_64.rpm
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Local Package Process
Examining /home/mono/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/libpng12-devel-1.2.50-3.el6.x86_64.rpm: libpng12-devel-1.2.50-3.el6.x86_64
Marking /home/mono/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/libpng12-devel-1.2.50-3.el6.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.net.cen.ct.gov
 * extras: mirror.dattobackup.com
 * rpmforge: repoforge.mirror.constant.com
 * updates: mirror.umd.edu
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libpng12-devel.x86_64 0:1.2.50-3.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: libpng12-devel-1.2.50-3.el6.x86_64 conflicts libpng-devel
No package matched to upgrade: libpng12-devel
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: libpng12-devel conflicts with 2:libpng-devel-1.5.13-2.el6.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
[mono@localhost ~]$ sudo yum --nogpgcheck localupdate ~/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/libpng12-devel-1.2.50-3.el6.x86_64.rpm
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Local Package Process
Examining /home/mono/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/libpng12-devel-1.2.50-3.el6.x86_64.rpm: libpng12-devel-1.2.50-3.el6.x86_64
Package libpng12-devel not installed, cannot update it. Run yum install to install it instead.
Nothing to do
[mono@localhost ~]$
```

Is there any way I can delete one rpm and add another in the same command? Is there a multi-command RPM transaction? RPM transactions seem to be for historical auditing, so I think I'm googling for the wrong word. I need to swap out these RPMs a lot on my system, so if there is a way to link them by modifying the rpm spec and rebuilding it that's acceptable too.

Comment: CentOS 6 ships with libpng 1.2.  Why not 'yum downgrade libpng'?

Comment: Tried that, didn't work. Updated question

Comment: I can't say for certain, but it appears you have sufficiently altered your CentOS install such that it can't even find packages in the CentOS Base repository with yum.  What *else* have you updated?

Comment: Pretty much all that: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/l6wwd69o2yadoea/4x4AXcqYC8/RPMS

Answer (score 3):

You typically don't do a remove (`-e`) and then an install. This will push RPM to want to remove any applications that depend on this RPM. Rather you want to do an upgrade.

```
$ rpm -Uvh libpng12-devel
```

If this package is in fact a drop in upgrade for "libpng" it will do the remove and install as a single move, thus pacifying the dependencies.

#### Use yum

Also I would use `yum` to do it too, it is able to help you out more than just regular RPM with trickier things like this. Use this command:

```
$ yum update libpng12-devel
```

You can also also install local RPMs with `yum`:

```
$ yum --nogpgcheck localinstall libpng12-devel....rpm
```

This will often times offer you up suggestions on how to cope best with these types of trickier package management operations.

Comment: Updated my answer. Is there a way I can add my local rpmbuild repo to /etc/yum.repos.d?

Comment: Yes you can follow these directions and create a `file://` repo: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37670_01/E37355/html/ol_create_repo.html

Answer (score 1):

Yup, `libpng` is a hot mess. Here are a few tips:

First, a sanity check:

```
package-cleanup --cleandupes
```

Swap usually works, but may require a bit of experimentation:

```
yum swap -- install libpng12 libpng12-devel -- remove libpng libpng-devel
```

And if you're feeling wily, you can always skip the multilib check:

```
--setopt=protected_multilib=false
```

Comment: I don't have this situation currently, but thanks for this answer. Didn't know about yum swap.